# Proper way to support native and forced 32bit builds

Tags: cmake

I want to be able to compile my project for the native arch (32bit or 64bit) and to be able to compile it for 32bit even on a 64bit host. Is adding an `option` and a bunch of `if`s with compile flags the only way to do it or are there better ways? I need to support UNIX makefiles and NMake makefiles.

Comment: are you aware of the cmake's toolchain file concept?

Comment: @user3188346 I didn't investigate that

Comment: I do believe it is the correct tool for you ;). Could you share some examples of the settings that depends on the native arch?

Comment: @user3188346 I need to pass `-m32` and different `-march` to gcc and I need to use slightly different commands for `ExternalProject_Add`

Comment: With Visual Studio solutions, we just supply the toolchain to the generator and it handles it.  Similarly, for MacOS we supply `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` on the command line when we run cmake.  I would be surprised if there wasn't something similar for unix Makefiles.

Comment: I guess if the toolchain file does not work for you, you have to choose the ifs.  similar question related to `-march` was posted on the CMake mailing list in October with no response. https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2015-October/061842.html So probably there is no built-in mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a toolchain file: Here is one provided by @malak

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m32)

# here is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH   /usr/i486-linux-gnu )

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Then usage is simply:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake /path/to/source
```

Also, here is some information straight from wiki.

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CmakeMingw

I am not familiar with Nmake, but this article seems to have some similar information: http://nmake.alcatel-lucent.com/faq/32and64bit.html